# Join table with diferent user roles

Tags: mysql, join, union

I am trying to join one table that contains apponintments with a table that contains user info, its a wordpress user table so the user data is stored as a vertical table (not sure about that term)

What I have is something like this:

Appointments table

| id | appointment_date | doctor_id | patient_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-02-15 | 02 | 04 |
| 2 | 2023-02-18 | 03 | 04 |

Users table

| user_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02 | first_name | 'doctorname2' |
| 02 | last_name | 'doctorLname2' |
| 03 | first_name | 'doctorname3' |
| 03 | last_name | 'doctorLname3' |
| 04 | first_name | 'patientname4' |
| 04 | last_name | 'patientLname4' |

With the following Query I can get the doctor or the patient of the appointment but not both

```
SELECT id, appointment_date, 
       max(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'first_name' THEN meta_value END) AS name,
       max(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'last_name' THEN meta_value END) AS last_name
FROM      appointments
LEFT JOIN usermeta ON doctor_id = user_id
GROUP BY id
```

| id | appointment_date | name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2023-02-15 | 'doctorname2' | 'doctorLname2' |
| 02 | 2023-02-18 | 'doctorname3' | 'doctorLname3' |

I need some help to get this table

| id | appointment_date | dr_name | dr_last_name | pat_name | pat_last_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2023-02-15 | 'doctorname2' | 'doctorLname2' | 'patientname4' | 'patientLname4' |
| 02 | 2023-02-18 | 'doctorname3' | 'doctorLname3' | 'patientname4' | 'patientLname4' |

I have tried Unions but with no success.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Your expected output tables are empty. Update your post such that your expected output reflects the application of the correct query over your sample input data.

Comment: My bad, I did not specify the sample data correctly, but I think its better now.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one issue in your query: you can't join your appointments table both on doctors and patients. You need two join operations for that.

Also you're missing the "*appointment_date*" field inside the `GROUP BY` clause. There may be errors or subtle issues if all non-aggregated (and selected) fields are not found within that clause.

A minor change: you don't need left joins, assuming that your "*Users*" table contains all possible users (hence users contained in the appointments table is a subset).

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.appointment_date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN doctors.meta_key = 'first_name'
                THEN doctors.meta_value              END) AS dr_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN doctors.meta_key = 'last_name'
                THEN doctors.meta_value              END) AS dr_last_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN patients.meta_key = 'first_name'
                THEN patients.meta_value             END) AS pt_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN patients.meta_key = 'last_name'
                THEN patients.meta_value             END) AS pt_last_name
FROM       appointments a
INNER JOIN usermeta     doctors
        ON a.doctor_id = doctors.user_id
INNER JOIN usermeta     patients
        ON a.patient_id = patients.user_id
GROUP BY a.id, a.appointment_date
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vcQFByfrFfWF9YiVExi9gJ/0).

Comment: Thank you!, it solved my need and taught me so much.